# Importing very large SQL query

Tags: sql-server, import, ssms

I'm trying to import a very large .sql query. My problem is that it weighs 15GB (it is a confluence server dump). I need to import it to SSMS, but it has a limit of 300MB. Got any ideas?

Here is a sample:

```
    --
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--
-- Dumped from database version 9.5.24
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 9.5.24
SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;
--
-- Name: plpgsql; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -; Owner: 
--
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;
--
-- Name: EXTENSION plpgsql; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner: 
--
COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language';
SET default_tablespace = '';
SET default_with_oids = false;
--
-- Name: AO_187CCC_SIDEBAR_LINK; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: confluenceuser
--
CREATE TABLE public."AO_187CCC_SIDEBAR_LINK" (
    "CATEGORY" character varying(255),
    "CUSTOM_ICON_CLASS" character varying(255),
    "CUSTOM_TITLE" character varying(255),
    "DEST_PAGE_ID" bigint DEFAULT 0,
    "HARDCODED_URL" character varying(255),
    "HIDDEN" boolean,
    "ID" integer NOT NULL,
    "POSITION" integer DEFAULT 0,
    "SPACE_KEY" character varying(255),
    "TYPE" character varying(255),
    "WEB_ITEM_KEY" character varying(255)
);
ALTER TABLE public."AO_187CCC_SIDEBAR_LINK" OWNER TO confluenceuser;
--
-- Name: AO_187CCC_SIDEBAR_LINK_ID_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: confluenceuser
--
CREATE SEQUENCE public."AO_187CCC_SIDEBAR_LINK_ID_seq"
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE public."AO_187CCC_SIDEBAR_LINK_ID_seq" OWNER TO confluenceuser;
--
-- Name: AO_187CCC_SIDEBAR_LINK_ID_seq; Type: SEQUENCE OWNED BY; Schema: public; Owner: confluenceuser
--
ALTER SEQUENCE public."AO_187CCC_SIDEBAR_LINK_ID_seq" OWNED BY public."AO_187CCC_SIDEBAR_LINK"."ID";
--
-- Name: AO_21D670_WHITELIST_RULES; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: confluenceuser
```

There are a total of 38mil lines of this.

Comment: Don't try to open it in SSMS. You'll want to run the batches contained in the files using something like `sqlcmd`. Or you could split the file into multiple files, but that would need to done at the end that create s the file(s).

Comment: When I tried to run sqlcmd it just hung there for a while and then cmd crashed.
I have a sql server set up locally on my PC. I ran the command 
sqlcmd -S DESKTOP-VBMKRU0\CONFLUENCEDB -i C:\<my file location and name>.sql

Comment: If the file is 15GB, I wouldn't be surprised if the run time is... well long. Depending on how [well] the SQL is written (for example, many `INSERT` statements that `INSERT` single rows, rather than a few that `INSERT` many (thousands)), it could honestly take days.

Comment: Would there be any other way to import this file?

Comment: Like I mentioned, perhaps you should be looking at the process that creates the file, not the one that consumes it.

Comment: So, thing is, this file was created so that I have access to confluence database. Our server hosts were unable to grant me a live connection to the DB (which would solve this issue), so instead they exported this file. As You can see, I'm kinda stuck with this whole process...

Comment: You might have to process the file with some sort of client software that can do bulk inserts. If you can [edit] your post with a small sample of the file we can see what could be done

Comment: hey, made an edit with a code sample.

Comment: What do you `INSERT` statements look like, @EdgarsR.Dunis ? Feel free to anonymise, they just need to be representative.

Comment: Also `"HIDDEN" boolean`? That won't work; there's no `boolean` data type in SQL Server.

Comment: OK you are going to need a proper piece of software for this, and you are going to need to analyze what the database contains. You have a huge Postgresql script, and SQL Server is very different in what it supports and how